# Summation of Selection Sort

Tags: algorithm, big-o, selection-sort

I'm working through the algorithm design manual and stuck on understanding the summation behind selection sort in Chapter 2.

1. Can someone explain how this summation is simplifed? For example, How do we get to n - i - 1?
2. if n = 8, then s(n) is (8 - 1) + (8 - 2) + (8 - 3) etc. What does the result of this mean in relation to the formula? I've included a screenshot of the paragrah and my notes for context. [screenshot of selection sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IxRi.png)

Comment: You mean https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csum_%7Bj%3Di%2B1%7D%5E%7Bn-1%7D+1?

Comment: sorry, really sure what you're asking @Neil I clicked the link and it's similar to the problem in the screenshot but I'm still unclear about what adding all the integers means.

Comment: This is not apparently obvious; I will write up a short answer.

Comment: It is better to edit to include that image directly in your text, than someone with the same question can have an easier time finding it. (I assume that's why someone has downvoted.)

Answer (score 0):

> `\sum_{i=0}^{j-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1} 1 = \sum_{i=0}^{j-1} n - i - 1`, why this, where is `j`?

You were asking about the simplifying step with which the index `j` is summed over. [This link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3698295) goes more in detail, but in general,

```
\sum_{j=u}^{v} 1 = -u + v + 1
```

is equivalent to this pseudo-code,

```
sum = 0
for(int j = u; j <= v; j++)
    sum += (f(j) = 1)
return sum
```

For example, with `u=3` and `v=22`, it would be `sum = u - v + 1 = 22 - 3 + 1 = 20`.

[image: A graphical representation.]

With `-u + v + 1` at `u = i+1` and `v = n-1` it simplifies to `-(i+1) + (n-1) + 1 = n - i - 1`.

> if `n=8` does `\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} n - i - 1` refer to `(8-1) + (8-2) + (8-3) + ... + 2 + 1 [+ 0]`, why two different kinds of values?

It has been simplified from `(8-0-1) + (8-1-1) + (8-2-1) + ... (8-5-1) + (8-6-1) + (8-7-1)`.